# Remove particle from box2d.world.getParticlePositionBuffer()

Tags: processing, box2d, particle-system

How to remove a particle from box2d.world when it get out of screen?

Currently, I have this code from [Nature of Code - LiquidFunTest](https://github.com/shiffman/The-Nature-of-Code-Examples/blob/master/chp05_physicslibraries/box2d/LiquidFunTest/LiquidFunTest.pde#L66) example:

```
Vec2[] positionBuffer = box2d.world.getParticlePositionBuffer();
if (positionBuffer != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < positionBuffer.length; i++) {
    Vec2 pos = box2d.coordWorldToPixels(positionBuffer[i]);
    pg.stroke(255);
    pg.strokeWeight(3);
    pg.point(pos.x, pos.y);
  }
}
```

I've changed the code to:

```
Vec2[] positionBuffer = box2d.world.getParticlePositionBuffer();
if (positionBuffer != null) {

  for (int i = 0; i < positionBuffer.length; i++) {
    Vec2 pos = box2d.coordWorldToPixels(positionBuffer[i]);
    if(pos.y > height){
      box2d.world.destroyParticle(i);
    } else {
      pg.stroke(255);
      pg.strokeWeight(3);
      pg.point(pos.x, pos.y);
    }
  }
}
```

But `destroyParticle()` method doesn't have the same index as `getParticlePositionBuffer()`

Comment: First, check whether the position is outside the screen. If so, remove it from the box2d simulation. Which of those are you stuck on?

Comment: @KevinWorkman please take a look on the edited question... I'm checking position, but how to destroy a particle on the position buffer?